# Trim escape characters from file path

Tags: terminal, finder, automator

I generate file paths for use in emails by dragging the folder/file in question into Terminal.app then copying & pasting the generated text into an email text.

The copied path with escape sequences:

```
pCloud\ Drive/SEN\ pCloud/SEN\ Tech\ Team/Clean\ Energy\ WA\ Study\2016/For\ checking/AB\ checks/SEN\ RE\ SWIS\ 2030\ notes\ for\ AB\checks\ -\ Backup\ input\ table\ tab\ \(5.1.16\).docx
```

needs to become like this:

```
pCloud Drive/SEN pCloud/SEN Tech Team/Clean Energy WA Study 2016/For checking/AB checks/SEN RE SWIS 2030 notes for AB\checks - Backup input table tab \(5.1.16\).docx
```

I am looking for a quick way to zap all the occurrences of backslash character escaping the space character. Someone mentioned a Finder trick for doing that, but now I've forgotten it.

I tried to create a Finder Service to do a simple Find & Replace in Automator but couldn't get it done. Automator will allow me to make it appear in Applications under Services (although on my current macOS I don't seem to see that menu, maybe I need to do something to enable it).

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Is this a case of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I probably do do that somethings but in this case I don't think so. Quote: "Someone mentioned a Finder trick for doing that, but now I've forgotten it." The correct answer mentioned exactly that. But other processes have their advantages, as other functions can be added to a Automator routine or perl script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag into TextEdit instead of Terminal. TextEdit won't add backslashes to the text.

You can still use Terminal, though. If you type `echo`, then drag and drop into Terminal, and then hit enter, the backslashes will be removed (actually, they're there precisely to allow terminal commands to handle the raw input -- `echo` doesn't see backslashes, but a single argument containing space characters).

```
$ echo pCloud\ Drive/SEN\ pCloud/SEN\ Tech\ Team/Clean\ Energy\ WA\ Study\2016/For\ checking/AB\ checks/SEN\ RE\ SWIS\ 2030\ notes\ for\ AB\checks\ -\ Backup\ input\ table\ tab\ \(5.1.16\).docx
pCloud Drive/SEN pCloud/SEN Tech Team/Clean Energy WA Study2016/For checking/AB checks/SEN RE SWIS 2030 notes for ABchecks - Backup input table tab (5.1.16).docx
```

Furthermore, you can automate the copying of the text by piping to `pbcopy`:

```
$ echo pCloud\ Drive/SEN\ pCloud/SEN\ Tech\ Team/Clean\ Energy\ WA\ Study\2016/For\ checking/AB\ checks/SEN\ RE\ SWIS\ 2030\ notes\ for\ AB\checks\ -\ Backup\ input\ table\ tab\ \(5.1.16\).docx | pbcopy
```

Now the desired text will be on your clipboard.

Comment: On a old version of OS X, I have a shell function `fn2pb`- filename to pasteboard, where the guts of the function are `pbcopy <<<"$@"`. So I type `fn2pb ` then drag a file onto the Terminal.app window.

Answer (score 7):

- Select a file with a right click
- Hold down the Option key
- Select the menu item *Copy "filename" as Pathname*

Note: I believe this only works in  El Capitan and above.

Comment: Excellent answer! I am aware of this technique, yet somehow it didn't occur to me :) I ended up learning about and writing an Automator workflow containing perl script to zap slashes. Was using a sword where a needle could do :-|

Comment: Thanks. Will do that :) Can you edit your answer to mention this constraint?

Comment: It works in El Capitan, so as of this answer, it works in all *current* versions of macOS.

Comment: Thanks someone had told me that but I couldn't remember it! I was trying to paste into the Goto Folder command and things like that (which didn't help).

Comment: @NimeshNeema Please link to the Automator flow or make a new answer here. I'd like to use it and add some other features (like swap "➝" for the folder delimiter character "/", change the font, size etc) and make it a Service I can invoke in Mail or Finder.

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil Sure, I'll post a new answer shortly.

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil I have added my answer which uses Automator workflow.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach using Automator service:

1. Launch Automator.app.
2. In the Menu bar, go to File → New → Service.
3. In the editor area, set options as:

   - **Service receives selected**: `text`
   - **in**: `any application`
   - **Output replaces selected text**: `select check-mark`
4. In the right sidebar, select Library → Utilities → Run Shell Script action.
5. Drag & drop the action into editor area.
6. Under **Run Shell Script*, set options as:

   - **Shell**: `/bin/bash`
   - **Pass input**: `to stdin`
7. Under the **Run Shell Script** editor area, type the following `sed` command-line:

   `sed 's/\\\ /\ /g'`

   Note that the script also contain spaces characters. Advisable to edit this post and copy the script as is.
8. In the Automator menu, click File → Save... and save the service with a suitable name.
9. Now whenever you will select the text in any app and right-click, you can see the service under **Service** context menu item.
10. Upon invoking the service, all the occurrences of backslash followed by space character will be replaced by just the space character.

Comment: Yes this is my current method, but looking for something one-click because I use it so much.

Comment: Suggested this as you are already copy pasting the text manually from Terminal. This approach indeed adds an additional hop.

Comment: Thx Nimesh. If I want to change is so that all escaped characters like say "\&" what would I change the sed script to? Is it using Grep, it seems to be something unlike Grep.